# jQuery Mobile: Prevent node being deleted on history back

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this code

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on("swipeleft", jqmForward).on("swiperight", jqmBack);
});

function jqmBack(e) {
  var prevpage = $('div.ui-page-active').prevAll('div[data-role="page"]');
  if (prevpage.length > 0)
    $.mobile.changePage($(prevpage[0]), { transition: "slide", reverse: true }, true, true);
}
function jqmForward(e) {
  var nextpage = $('div.ui-page-active').nextAll('div[data-role="page"]');
  if (nextpage.length > 0)
    $.mobile.changePage($(nextpage[0]), "slide", false, true);
}
```

But the forward function never works because apparently jqm deletes the latest `div.ui-page` when you go back.

Is there a way to keep the `div.ui-page` to let you go forward after you accidentally swipe right (ie. go back)?

<sup>I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.0</sup>

Comment: JQM doesn't delete any page in _multi page model_. Try `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")` instead of `$('div.ui-page-active')`.

Comment: It actually does. See [Caching pages in DOM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-cache.html). That code doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In single page model it does remove pages. In multi-page it doesn't.

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean, of course haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have

```
$(function () {
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
```

(see [Caching pages in DOM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-cache.html)). But that rises [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003346/using-jquery-mobile-dom-cache-just-for-back-forward-history-navigation).