# Using jQuery Mobile DOM cache for back/forward history navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile

I implemented [swipe for history back/forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001749/jquery-mobile-cannot-go-forward-because-node-is-deleted-when-going-back), together with [caching the DOM](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-cache.html).

Say this is the page structure

```
Homepage
  Page 1
    Page 1A
  Page 2
```

When you navigate as follows:

Homepage > Page 1 > Page 1A

The 3 pages are cached

```
<div data-url="home.aspx">...
<div data-url="page1.aspx">...
<div data-url="page1a.aspx" class="ui-page-active">...
```

If you then go back twice (to the Homepage) and go to Page2, Page 1 and 1A are still cached :(

```
<div data-url="home.aspx">...
<div data-url="page1.aspx">...
<div data-url="page1a.aspx">...
<div data-url="page2.aspx" class="ui-page-active">...
```

If you now swipe back from Page 2, you will get to Page 1A. This will also make the cache huge.

How do you clear Page 1 and 1A out of the cache as soon as you go to Page 2?
So it should be like this:

```
<div data-url="home.aspx">...
<div data-url="page2.aspx" class="ui-page-active">...
```

In other words, I want the swipe to work exactly like any browser back/forward button.
(I need the swipe for improved UX because there are no dedicated back/forward buttons on mobile phones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem.

```
$("body").on("pagecontainerbeforeload", function(event,ui) {
  $('div.ui-page-active').nextAll('div[data-role="page"]').remove();
});
```

So everytime you click a link it will delete all pages after the currently active node.